# Number of ways of selecting a team of $4$ if it contains at least $2$ females

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So here is the question

> A team of $4$ is chosen from $7$ males and $9$ females.
>
> 1) Find the number of the ways of selecting the committee if it must contain $2$ of each sex.

Will the answer be $7C2 \times 9C2$?

> 2) and if it contain at least $2$ females ?

Will the answer be $14C2$ OR $7C2 \times 9C2 + 7C1 \times 9C3$?

Comment: Yes?!?!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: Hint: at least 2 females in a committee of 4 means 2, 3, or 4 females.

Comment: Is it a team, Peggy, or is it a committee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is correct. 
Your second answer to the second question is almost correct. You just missed the number of ways when the team has $4$ females i. e. $7C0×9C4$ (recall that $7C0=1$). Therefore the correct answer to the second question  is (using the binomial notation)
$$\binom{7}{2}\cdot \binom{9}{2}+\binom{7}{1}\cdot \binom{9}{3}+\binom{7}{0}\cdot \binom{9}{4}=1470.$$
You may obtain the same result by noting that "at least 2 females" is the complement of "at most 1 female". Therefore 
$$\underbrace{\binom{7+9}{4}}_{\text{all teams of 4 people}}
-\underbrace{\binom{7}{4}\cdot \binom{9}{0}}_{\text{all teams of 4 males}}-\underbrace{\binom{7}{3}\cdot\binom{9}{1}}_{\text{all teams of 3 males and 1 female}}=1470.$$